# Using T-SQL 'Two Digit Year Cutoff' in script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a script to cleanup some data, converting dates stored in an varchar field from dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy format. (yes, I know, but not my design :)

I've got a script written to do this, but I've currently got a hardcoded constant of 2049 as the cutoff date.  I know SQL has a 'Two Digit Year Cutoff' advanced option, which I'd like to use in place of this constant.

Is there a safe/convenient way to retrieve and use this in a script?
(Needs to support SQL-Server 2005/2008/2008R2)

Comment: Why not just store it as a DATETIME instead...?

Comment: Agreed, don't store date values in a character field; that way lies madness.  Aspecially because your chosen format doesn't sort/index nicely.

Comment: Couldnt agree more, but its not my design, and I cant change the schema for this release.  This is to clean up some legacy data to resolve a specific issue.

Comment: Can you show us your script please? I don't understand your question. Are you wanting to go beyond 2049? I don't even know why SQL sets that cut off in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT value
FROM sys.configurations 
WHERE name = 'two digit year cutoff'
```

But can't you just convert (assuming that your system is setup to use dd/mm/yyy as a standard) to a datetime, and then back again?

Comment: My first cut of the script did exactly that, but I cant be sure the system will be setup with dd/mm/yyyy format, and didnt want to change it on the fly.  This works great though, thanks.